# Excel VBA - Insert value (text) in one column, if another column contains another value (text)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I've looked around the forum, and haven't been able to adapt anything successfully, so here I am. This is my current task:

If cell in `Column A` has the value "*Info*", then insert the value "Header" into the corresponding row in Column I (overwriting whatever is there)

Final note: This should work for whatever ActiveSheet I am running the Macro on.

Comment: I you had been on the site looking around you would know that this is not a code for me site.  Please post what you have tried and tell us where it fails.

Comment: The code is out there Nate.  When searching google for vba questions do it in this format:  Put the following into the google search box: vba excel change cell content based on another column content

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code,

```
Sub info()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "Info" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("I" & i) = "Header"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Note:- The word `Info` is case sensitive